# itextsharp stamper vs smartcopy, show pdf in browser without toolbar or navpanes

Tags: pdf, iframe, itext

My application is grabbing pdf bytes from our db and sending the pdf to an iframe, using the itextsharp library. When the pdf is displayed in the iframe, the toolbar and navigation pane show, but we'd like to hide those. When I load a pdf document by simply typing in the pdf's url with #toolbar=0&navpanes=0, I see the result I'm looking for.

The application logic is using PdfStamper to add some buttons and other data to the pdf. When I write the pdf to the Response.Outputstream, the pdf shows up with the added buttons, and all is good except that I can't get rid of the toolbar and navpanes. I've tried adding "toolbar=0&navpanes=0" to the url in the response header, but to no avail.

I've written a test application which shows that using PdfSmartCopy instead of the stamper works perfectly - the pdf is shown in the browser which hides the toolbar and navpane by default.

The problem is that I still need to add some buttons to the pdf via the stamper. I've written a test app which adds the buttons via the stamper, then the smart copy grabs each page from the stamper and writes all this out to the Response.Output. The pdf shows in the browser with no toolbar or navpanes, but the buttons are not there.

Here is the code which uses both the stamper and the smart copy - your help is greatly appreciated:

```
private void SendStamperToCopy()
{
    try
    {
        String filePath = @"C:\debug\PerfIndicWithDefaults.pdf";
        byte[] pdfBytes = ReadFile(filePath);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream);


        // add a button with the stamper
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectCancel = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50, 50, 20, 20);
        PushbuttonField btnCancel = new PushbuttonField(pdfStamper.Writer, rectCancel, "Cancel");
        btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation fieldCancel = btnCancel.Field;
        pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(fieldCancel, 1);

        int numOfPgs = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int n = 1; n <= numOfPgs; n++)
        {
            copy.AddPage(pdfStamper.GetImportedPage(reader, n));
        }


        String headerStr = "inline; filename=PerfIndicWithDefaults.pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", headerStr);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        document.Close();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, your code contains a serious logical error. This is not supposed to work. If I compare your description with the code, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve because of a number of contradictions. Could you simplify your use case so that I can understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use `PdfStamper` to add a button and you want to change the viewer preferences. This can be done like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, m);     
PdfStamper.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.HideToolbar | PdfWriter.PageModeUseNone;   
stamper.Close(); 
reader.Close();
```

The `HideToolbar` will hide the toolbar, whereas `PageModeUseNone` means that you don't show any panels (such as the bookmarks panel, etc...).

It is not clear why you would need `PdfSmartCopy` in this context. Maybe I'm missing something. Also: there are some strange errors in your code: you never close the `stamper` instance, yet you import a page from the `stamper` into the `copy` instance. I've never seen any one try that. It's certainly not what I had in mind when I wrote iText. Your code is very confusing to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try all of the simple examples that I found in the book and online. Everything works very well when I save the pdf to an actual file. The problem happens when I write the same pdf to the OutputStream of an http response. When written to an http response/to a browser, the Viewer Preferences are not honored - the tool bar and navigation panes are showing when I use the PDFStamper. When I use PdfSmartCopy the viewer preference are honored.

Comment: So you are saying that my code works when you save the PDF to a file, but not when you send the same bytes to an output stream?

Comment: Then something else is at play, because iText merely produces bytes. It doesn't matter if you write these bytes to a file or to another output stream. If you want to debug your application, you'll have to look elsewhere: the problem isn't caused by iText, but maybe by another error in your code.